# List report with each line showing percentage of one specific line

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI report with multiple lines (it's a P and L report) displayed in a list visualisation.

It's populated from a view in SQL

One of the lines is 'Total Revenue'

I need every line to display its proportion of Total Revenue as a percentage:

i.e.

```
LINE           MTH     %
------------------------
Line1            5    10 
Total Revenue   50   100
Line2           20    40
Line3            4     8
Line4           12    24
```

Note that `MTH` does not add up to total revenue so I can't just take the total, I need to take the line called Total Revenue as the denominator

Here is the perfect example of what I'm trying to do here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634760.aspx

But when I try this method (firstly just to get the denominator), I only get a value on the Total Revenue line and blanks on the other lines, like this:

```
LINE           MTH     %
------------------------
Line1            5    
Total Revenue   50    50
Line2           20    
Line3            4    
Line4           12
```

Here's my DAX:

```
MTH% = 
  SUMX(
      CALCULATETABLE(
         'vw_PandL',
         'vw_PandL'[Line]="TOTAL REVENUE"
          )
       ,
          [MTH]
  )
```

As far as I can tell, the only difference between my expression and the example on the web page, is that the web page uses a *separate* dimension to filter the row, whereas may expression uses a column in the *same* table to filter the row

Example Given on web page:

```
=SUMX( CALCULATETABLE(
        'InternetSales_USD', 
        'DateTime'[CalendarYear]=2006
     )  
 , [SalesAmount_USD])
```

Based on comments below this should work, but it doesn't work for me

I've now also tried:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM([MTH]),
    FILTER(ALL('vw_PandL'),
        [Line]="TOTAL REVENUE")
        )
```

Which gets me the grand total on all lines for TOTAL REVENUE, but ignores report filters. This is closer.

The  `ALLEXCEPT` function is meant to unfilter everything except the designated columns, however when I try this, I get the same result. It still doesn't take note of my date and site filters:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM([MTH]),
    FILTER(ALLEXCEPT('vw_PandL','vw_PandL'[DateKey],'vw_PandL'[DimSiteKey]),
        [Line]="TOTAL REVENUE")
        )
```

**Update 1:**

I managed to reproduce this in a simple model

Among many things what I didn't mention is that the `LINE` column is sorted by another column called `SortZZ`

The calc posed in @Foxan Ng answer works perfectly but as soon as I sort the Line column, it exhibits the behaviour I mentioned: the Total Revenue figure only appears on the Total Revenue line

After further investigation: I don't even need to sort it, I can just put the SortZZ column in the list and it will break the calc.

**Solution**

The final functioning calc was:

```
Total Revenue = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM([MTH]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT('vw_PandL','vw_DimPeriod'[Period],'DimSite'[Site]),
        'vw_PandL'[Line] = "Total Revenue")
)
```

The trick is in `ALLEXCEPT`

My relationships and slicers are set up as follows:

- `vw_PandL` is a fact table
- `vw_DimPeriod` is joined to it on `PeriodCode`
- `DimSite` is also joined to it on `SiteKey`

When using any of the following `ALLEXCEPT` expressions, the calculation did not honour my slicers. That is, the figure was the grand total for the line across all periods and sites:

1. Referring to join keys in fact table:

   `ALLEXCEPT('vw_PandL','vw_PandL'[PeriodCode],'vw_PandL'[SiteKey])`
2. Referring to join keys in dimensions:

   `ALLEXCEPT('vw_PandL','vw_DimPeriod'[PeriodCode],'DimSite'[SiteKey])`

The only way I could get the calc to honour my slicers was to use the actual field that I was physically using in my slicer, in other words the label

```
ALLEXCEPT('vw_PandL','vw_DimPeriod'[Period],'DimSite'[SiteName])
```

The key thing to learn from this is this is not just a relational database where you join on a key then filtering on the label will work. The columns and tables mentioned in these functions are very important.

Comment: In the example you've given above (the table with LINE and MTH columns, and the corresponding DAX), the MTH% column calculates as you expect (50 for all rows). I'm not able to replicate the situation you describe where 50 only appears on the Total Revenue line.

Comment: Thanks for your response - well that gives me something to go on

Comment: I've made some edits. Now I've found something that gets me a result on every line, but I have filters and these are not being applied

Comment: Problems with filtering can be very data model dependent (e.g. if you're filtering on a dimensional attribute and your measure references the fact table key, it can behave unexpectedly). Is it possible you can expand on your sample table above so that it recreates what's wrong in your main model? E.g. add in dimension keys, more rows (I assume you have multiple TOTAL REVENUE rows for example), and sample dimension tables (plus indicate which column(s) you're filtering on that aren't working)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you provided actually works, except that you should create it as a `Measure` instead of a `Calculated Column`. `Measure` works with filter while `Calculated Column` would remain the same even there are filters applied.

Create a `Measure` called `Total Revenue`:

```
Total Revenue = 
SUMX(
    CALCULATETABLE(
        'vw_PandL',
        'vw_PandL'[Line] = "Total Revenue"
    ),
    [MTH]
)
```

Create another `Measure` called `%`:

```
% = VALUES(vw_PandL[MTH]) / [Total Revenue]
```

And it will work with filters applied.

For Year 2015:
[image: 2015]

For Year 2016:
[image: 2016]

Depend on nature of the dataset, the `%` `Measure` can be modified as below so it will work without filters:

```
% = SUM(vw_PandL[MTH]) / [Total Revenue]
```

Result:
[image: Total]

Hope it helps.

---

Edit:

I changed the `Total Revenue` to the alternative solution you provided and it works with the sorted column case:

```
Total Revenue = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM([MTH]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT('vw_PandL', vw_PandL[DateKey]),
        [Line] = "Total Revenue"
    )
)
```

No filter:
[image: sorted, no filter]

Filter applied:
[image: sorted, filter applied]

Comment: Thank you. I do very much appreciate you taking the time to cook up an example. You are the second person to demonstrate that this does function as described. However when I use this calc it only appears on the Total Revenue Line. It does not repeat on the other lines. Clearly there must be something I'm doing differently, so I will recreate as you have and try and work out what the difference is. Thanks again

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid When I created the "Total Revenue" as a "Column", it appears only on the row with "Total Revenue". When I created it as a "Measure", it appears on every row. Is this possibly what you're facing?

Comment: It's definitely a measure. I couldn't see it as a column in the table tab (so it's not a column) but anyway I deleted and recreated it with _right click / new measure_ and I've copy pasted your exact expression and the other rows are definitely blank. I'm convinced there is some issue with my model. Could it possibly be because the the "line" column is in the fact table rather than being a separate dimension? In your working example, is _Line_ a column in a separate dimension or is it in the fact table (the same table that `MTH` is in)?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've created only one table. You can find the .pbix file here: http://www.filedropper.com/41608537 and see if it helps troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. You're right it definitely works. I'm perplexed. There is something obvious that I'm missing. Unfortunately (fortunately for you maybe) I can't share mine back. I'll take a break now and have another got tomorrow. Thanks for sticking with me. I am so looking forward to the Eureka moment on this one!

Comment: Hi there, I managed to reproduce this now - please see my edit. When the data is sorted it exhibits this behaviour. Any feedback appreciated

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Solution updated. It seems that there will be unexpected behaviors if you use SUMX() with sorted columns. Let's see if the alternative solution works for you.

Comment: That works perfectly in the sample Power BI model you uploaded but alas in my model the DateKey doesn't appear to be filtered (it's sliced from another table). The figure shown is the grand total regardless of filters. I haven't once got `ALLEXCEPT` to function. Clearly there's something I don't understand.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I think the problem is either you have to establish a correct relationship among the tables involved in the calculation, or you can use the field which is in the same table as filter. The DateKey used in the ALLEXCEPT function should be from the same table as the DateKey you used as filter.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. That has confused me a lot. In the relational world if you have two joined tables you can filter on either table and get the same result. Not the case here I think. I'm trying to work out the syntax.

Comment: I used `ALLEXCEPT('vw_PandL',vw_DimPeriod[PeriodCode]),` but there is no difference to the data - the total is not being filtered by my period slicer. vw_DimPeriod is related (single filter direction) to vw_PandL on `PeriodCode`

Comment: OMG I have it. it's only taken two days. Thank you oh SO MUCH for your help. I will post an edit

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct, because it _is_ correct based on the info I gave.